# Building Tensorflow 1.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

I have an old Macbook Pro 3,1 running ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.8. The mac CPU doesn't have support for avx (Advanced Vector Extensions) which is needed for tensorflow 2.2 so whilst tensorflow installs, it fails to run with the error:

> illegal instruction (core dumped)

I've surfed around and it seems that I need to use tensorflow 1.5 however there is no wheel for this for my configuration and I have the impression that I need to build one for myself.

So here's my question... how do I even start to do that? Does anyone have a URL to Building-Stuff-For-Dummies or something similar please? (Any other suggestions also welcome)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If the goal is not building Tensorflow itself, but make it working, you may try anaconda. If you do `conda install tensorflow==1.5` it should take all the relevant libraries with it and many possible optimizations (on intel cpus it uses mkl version).

Comment: The goal is to try to get tensorflow working rather than build my own distribution. I tried pip install tensorflow==1.5 which didn't find a distribution. Will conda find a distribution and if it does, shouldn't it be possible to access it with pip? (I'm not very experienced with python and I've heard that mixing conda and pip can lead to overwriting files...)

Comment: `conda search tensorflow` shows that there's 1.5.0 version in it's repository. "Conda install" is different from "pip install", because it will take all the required libraries with it, should be easier for you

Comment: In conda you can create environment to avoid mixing with installed libraries

Comment: Interesting to know, Slowpoke. Thanks. (Specifically, are there limitations to the versions of python that the conda version 1.5 will run on? I'd rather avoid downgrading if possible)

Comment: Conda is a sort of a manager of python versions. You create environment with python version you want to use. If you want to use it always, you can add activation of this env to `~/.bashrc` (or what is on the Mac). I've checked presence of tensorflow 1.5 for python3.7. I'm sure it's present for 3.6.5 and 3.5

Comment: OK. Thanks. I know that tensorflow 1.5 runs with python 3.6 using the pip installation approach. I'm just installing 3.6 alongside the default 3.8 although I am having problems getting tkinter working (necessary for IDLE). Probably missed a path or something somewhere.

Comment: From quick googling, looks like corresponding conda package is `tk` (`conda install tk`)

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are instructions for building in the repository's README.md. Isn't there such for TensorFlow? It would be odd.

Comment: Thanks גל זיגלר.   
I followed the instructions in the README.md and got this error:
  
`ERROR: Skipping './tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': invalid target format './tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': invalid package name './tools/pip_package': package name component contains only '.' characters WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed. ERROR: invalid target format './tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': invalid package name './tools/pip_package': package name component contains only '.' characters`
  
Any ideas how to overcome that?

Comment: Seems the path format is doing the problem. Is that path was given by you? If not, perhaps it's a compatibility issue, and the version isn't suitable for the Python version you are using. I looked up yesterday, and TensorFlow does offer binaries for old versions via pip, as someone suggested you to do. Did you try doing that? It could save you the trouble of building it from the source.

Comment: No - when you unpack the tensorflow release that you download from the internet, it sets up a directory structure (with a directory called WORKSPACE in it) and you need to build from that tensorflow directory. The tools/pip_package directory is there by default

Comment: ...but I think you're right. I'll need to downgrade my version of python. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Think I have found the answer: [Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39768)

In summary. Tensorflow 1.x (and even Tensorflow 2.1) wasn't built for python 3.8 so it was never going to work.

Looks like I will need to downgrade my version of python to 3.6.

:-(

Answer (score 0):

Update: I installed python 3.6 alongside the default 3.8 and then installed tensorflow 1.5 and it looks like it works now (albeit with a few 'future warnings'.)